# How to show configurable product as related product with their options in Magento

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, product-attribute, related-products

The problem is that when I add a configurable product as a related product, it shows the product but there is no checkbox. I have read that in Magento2 when the related product is a configurable one it won't show the options and the checkbox. Is there a way to fix that??